# Templating solutions with built-in Memcached/Redis caching

Tags: caching, nginx, redis, memcached

During [FOWA](https://futureofwebapps.com/london-2014/schedule/day-1/) I saw [a talk by Wim Godden on SCL](http://www.slideshare.net/wimg/when-dynamic-becomes-static-the-next-step-in-web-caching-techniques) - a Nginx plugin offering a kind of html templates with built-in caching lookup using Memcache, offering control structures, ++. The bits of the page would be built up from other pages using this syntax:

```
<scl:include key="news" src="/news" ttl="5m" />
```

Problem is, it was supposed to be out *last year* in its open source incantation. So, are there any other alternatives out there?

Comment: Have you seen nginx ssi module? http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html

Comment: Great tip! I found a pretty good post on it here: 

http://kovyrin.net/2007/08/05/using-nginx-ssi-and-memcache-to-make-your-web-applications-faster/

But it was not complete, regarding examples with templating, etc. Care to fill out the details in an answer?